# Massively creating files with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have been trying to figure this out tried different commands and still have gotten no where. Can you please help me with this question?

In your home directory, create a subdirectory called shirts. Within the subdirectory, create 108 files with file names of the form style.size.color.ext, where each file contains one combination of values from the following table.

```
Style   tee, crew, turtleneck
Size    XXL, XL, L, M, S, XS
Color   red, yellow, blue
Extension   info, inv
```

This is the last command I used.

```
$ touch shirts/{tee,crew,turtleneck}.{XXL,XL,L,M,S,XS}.{red,yellow,blue}/{info,inv}
```

Comment: Did you already `mkdir shirts`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a slight error in your touch command. Your original command,

```
touch shirts/{tee,crew,turtleneck}.{XXL,XL,L,M,S,XS}.{red,yellow,blue}/{info,inv}
```

In the end there is a **/** which again tries to create a directory and since the directory doesn't exist you will get an error as,

```
touch: cannot touch `/shirts/turtleneck.XS.blue/inv': No such file or directory
```

However, since you need only files, you need to change your original command as,

```
touch shirts/{tee,crew,turtleneck}.{XXL,XL,L,M,S,XS}.{red,yellow,blue}.{info,inv}
```

**P.S**: You need to make sure that the directory `shirts` already exists. Otherwise, you will again get the same error `cannot touch`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the first time I attemped the command I did it correctly with the . instead of the / at the end. I did not do mkdir shirts. Its always something basic I over look. I am a new student thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. If this resolves the issue, please accept the answer so that the question is resolved :)

Comment: `its` is spelt `it's`: it is a contraction of `it is`. Where as `its` is a word used to announce the thing that belongs to it. e.g `its hat` (the hat that belongs to it).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor. I think it's more important to keep quotes balanced: don't you?

Comment: @Paul_pedant In English an apostrophe is not a quote. Or are you saying that you should have even parity in your apostrophes? Like in your comment.

Comment: Just a gentle pedantry. Although picking up on "its" but not "gotten", "no where" (or even "where as") seems inconsistent. (I acknowledge "ill-gotten gains" as idiomatic.)

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, the name of each of these 108 files should follow the format `style.size.color.ext`.

So it should be

```
mkdir shirts
touch {tee,crew,turtleneck}.{XXL,XL,L,M,S,XS}.{red,yellow,blue}.{info,inv}
```

What `touch` is doing is creating an empty file, but you are trying to create a directory shirts with different subdirectories. `touch` can't do that.

Edit: You can also make the `touch` cmd above shorter / look better:

```
touch {tee,crew,turtleneck}.{{X,XX,}L,M,{X,}S}.{red,yellow,blue}.{info,inv}
```